# Print result of .scrollTop in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show the value of the .scrollTop() function on the screen while I scroll up and down the page, but I can't get it to work. I'm obviously doing something stupid. Please enlighten me. :) Thank you.

```
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><p>.....</p></div>
<div id="long"></div>

<script> 

var $myVar = $('#myDiv');
var $myDist = $window.scrollTop();

$window.on('scroll', function(){
    $myVar.text($myDist);
});

</script>
</body>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MZBhk/1/

Ok, the solution was to cache the window, and to put .scrollTop() inside the curly braces. Thank you for your help. :)

Solution:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $myVar = $('#myDiv');
var $myDist = 0;

$window.on('scroll', function(){
    $myDist = $window.scrollTop();
    $myVar.html($myDist);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
$(window).scroll(function (){
   var scrPos = $(this).scrollTop();
   $('#myDiv').html('your Scroll Position is' + scrPos);
});
```

here i got the scroll postion and added it as html in the div which has id '#myDiv'

here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MZBhk/3/)

for more details on scroll http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you. The link about scroll is really helpful, I didn't realise this method existed!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$window` try `$(window)` and remove quots from `$myVar.text('$myDist')` and it should be  `$myVar.text($myDist)`.

Here is [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mo_esmp/H3A3a/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of scrollTop inside the 'scroll' event function.
So you have to do this:

```
<body>

  <div id="myDiv"><p>.....</p></div>
  <div id="long"></div>

  <script> 

    var $myVar = $('#myDiv');
    var $myDist = 0;

    $window.on('scroll', function(){
      $myDist = $(this).scrollTop()
      $myVar.text($myDist);
    });

  </script>
 </body>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting now.. first of all you should not write ur variable inside Quotes

```
 $myVar.text($myDist);
```

instead of

```
$myVar.text('$myDist');
```

Comment: I am not getting anything. My code is being ignored with or without the quotes around the variable name. :(